# Content Porter, Tree View Node Selection

Tags: 2011, content-porter-2013

I am importing content from machine A to B, Machine A has a blank publication and i want all children publication should be created by import (parent child relations is defined in blueprint hierarchy), while export wizard all elements in tree were selected by default but when I import to machine B, only some tree nodes are selected by default, If i don't select all nodes in import I get errors but If i select all nodes manually by expanding each tree nodes and traversing to last child, It works well.
I have 100s of nodes in tree and selecting each node and its children is not possible.

I have also tried to select the option with right click on each node and select children but it doesn't select nested children nodes.

Can anybody explain how this tree works?

Comment: I think a few screenshots might aid people in helping you out here. It's hard to visualise the problem you describe.

Comment: question updated with screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

I did not get your question as what do you mean by you have a publication and you want to import all child publication. You can select all the publications and its child by selecting the top most check box

Right click on the tree and you will get all the possible options - You can choose to select children only, select parent only, select parent and all children etc. option there.

May be more specific detail can help us provide you more concrete answer

Comment: when i right click on publication i get "publication and all children" option, I select this option, Now publication is selected but when i expand publication tree, nested folders and categories are not selected.

Comment: child publications means all publications inheriting from parent publication, I will create a blank parent publication and import should create all publications inheriting from parent.

Comment: Check with your permissions, you should get all children of your publication being selected if you click on the "publication and all children" option

Comment: How is it related to permission? I can select all children manually be expanding children nodes, I am using admin account btw.

Comment: in that case it is not related to the permission

Comment: May be you can provide few screenshots and also see if there is any error/warning in the event log

Comment: Ok, let me explain first problem, System A has 5 publications and System B is just fresh installation, I got export file from system A and want to import to system B, Do I need to create all publications manually on system B? Do I need to create all folders hierarchy to store schema files? Do I need to create same content hierarchy on system B before import?

Answer (score 1):

Select the top node (`IF Package`) to select all items in the package and be sure to uncheck the `Select items for import that we explicitly selected during export`.

You might get a subset of items if you're retrying a failed import and used `Generate batch of failed items for retry` or if you're *filtering* certain items on import (which shouldn't be selectable anyway).

Comment: There are 2 types of check boxes I can see in tree, If I check "IF Package", it selects all small checkboxes but doesn't check big checkboxes. for example in "keywords and Categories" section "Categories" are not checked but keywords for each category are checked. that means content porter will assume categories are already in the system and it will import keywords only.